# ngx_pagespeed admin statistics don't load

Tags: nginx, page-speed

I followed the [official install guide](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source) to build nginx with the latest stable pagespeed module. It works in some regards so I'd like to debug further with the admin tools. They are enabled in nginx as follows;

```
http {
    pagespeed FileCachePath "/mnt/ramdisk/ngx_pagespeed_cache";
    pagespeed StatisticsPath /ngx_pagespeed_statistics;
    pagespeed GlobalStatisticsPath /ngx_pagespeed_global_statistics;
    pagespeed MessagesPath /ngx_pagespeed_message;
    pagespeed ConsolePath /pagespeed_console;
    pagespeed AdminPath /pagespeed_admin;
    pagespeed GlobalAdminPath /pagespeed_global_admin;
}

server {
    location /ngx_pagespeed_statistics { allow 12.34.56.78; deny all; }
    location /ngx_pagespeed_global_statistics { allow 12.34.56.78; deny all; }
    location /ngx_pagespeed_message { allow 12.34.56.78; deny all; }
    location /pagespeed_console { allow 12.34.56.78; deny all; }
    location ~ ^/pagespeed_admin { allow 12.34.56.78; deny all; }
    location ~ ^/pagespeed_global_admin { allow 12.34.56.78; deny all; }

    pagespeed on;

    location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" {
        add_header "" "";
    }
    location ~ "^/pagespeed_static/" { }
    location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }
}
```

(Where 12.34.56.78 is my IP address)

When I visit https://example.org/ngx_pagespeed_statistics I see a brief glimpse of statistics before it says "Sorry, failed to update the statistics. Please wait and try again later."

In the browser inspector I see it tries to load `/ngx_pagespeed_statistics/stats_json` which returns a 404.

Did I miss a step in configuration? What could be the cause?